# How to get matrix induce L1 norm by Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

Using C++ Eigen library, how to get Matrix L1 norm?
If I use method `A.lpnorm<1>()` I can not get a Matrix L1 norm, instead, it returns sums of every abs of members in the Matrix.

```
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    MatrixXd A(2, 2);
    A << 375.0, 374.0,
        752.0, 750.0;
    std::cout << A << std::endl;

    std::cout << A.lpNorm<1>() << std::endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

this codes return:

```
// A
375 374
752 750

// A.lpNorm<1>()
2251
```

But what I want is this:

How to get matrix L1 norm by Eigen?

I get one solution:

```cpp
std::cout << "1-norm(mat)     = " << mat.cwiseAbs().colwise().sum().maxCoeff()
              << " == " << mat.colwise().lpNorm<1>().maxCoeff() << std::endl;
```

but it is not convenient. Are there other ways to retrieve the matrix L1 norm?

Comment: But … [the L1 norm is the sum of absolute values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014974/understanding-l1-and-l2-norms). What exactly do you want? What's the mathematical definition of the norm you want?

Comment: Matrix norms induced by vector 1-norms

Comment: I don't think there is a shorter version than the expression you found

Comment: Eigen's matrix norm is entry-wise (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entry-wise%22_matrix_norms). For the induced norm, either of your expression will do what you want. For convenience you could just put that into a function.

Comment: @苏茂江 I would suggest an edit but I am not sure I understand the problem fully. Your title question and the thing you are asking for seems to be two different things? Could you clarify for future readers?